# Find Missing Records

Tags: t-sql

My SQL is a bit bad. I got a query that when I run it I return for example 10 rows but there are 15 in my where clause, how do I identify those 5 that I can't find?

Off course I can dump it in MS Excel but how do I use SQL?

Its a simple query:

select * from customers where username in ("21051", "21052"...

Nothing else in the where clause, it return 10 rows but there are 15 usernames in there where clause.

Comment: If you post your query, and a dump of the 15 rows, someone can help you specifically.  Otherwise, I'd recommend just looking at the data, and trying to figure out where your query is failing.  It could be a problem with unexpected NULL values (?).

Comment: We can't answer this without at least the query you're running

Answer (score 1):

To identify the missing rows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT '21051' username 
      UNION ALL SELECT '21052'
      UNION ALL SELECT '21053'
      UNION ALL SELECT '21054') u 
WHERE u.username NOT IN (SELECT c.username FROM customers c)
```

Comment: Unfortuneately, this is the way to to it... that or, make a temp table, and insert the items into that table and then do the same query.